# Symfony2: Form with collection type problems

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, collections, autocomplete

I have a form (selling) which contain a collection of Articles (so the user can add as many articles as he needs).

Perhaps, the user MUST can add a new article if it doesn't exist in database.

I use autocomplete to retrieve articles by their name. So how to do when the user enter an article that doesn't exist in database ? Of course, the article must be added in database after.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, actually I tried nothing because I have no idea how to do it yet.. I'm thinking about giving the view two forms and send them by ajax.. will think about soon.